# Change font weight in a WPF label only for some parts

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a calculator and the results are shown in a label. Is it possible to set the result values (some string, some double) to display in bold?

My code looks like this:

```
 ...{
       label2.Content = "your time: " + saldoMin +
                    "     and:  " + fooNeg +
                    " " + inH +
                    " : " + inMin +
                    "  [h : min]\nyour factor: " + YourFactor +
                    "\n\ngo at: " + beginnH +
                    " : " + fooNull;
 }
```

and I only want the objects `saldoMin, fooNeg, inH, ...` to be bold, but not the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TextBlock with Runs. Here is an example:

```
var text = new TextBlock();
text.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Bold:")));
text.Inlines.Add(new Run(" nonbold"));
label2.Content = text;
```